# RabbitMQ/Kafka setup for messaging, payments system between users

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I have a need where I am working on a system which will have the following features:

- ~10 million users identified by a unique ID
- one user can send a text message to another user or to many users as part of a group
- one user can send a payment message to another user or to many users as part of a group
- one user can receive text message from a single user or many
- one user can receive a payment message from a single user or many
- The order in which the user receives a text or payment message have to be in the order of the UTC time the publishers sent them but the text message and payment message do not have to be queued they can be received async

What is the best way to setup this scenario using exchanges, queues, routing ids etc in RabbitMQ or using topics, partitions, client.id, consumer.id etc in Kafka? Also which is more suited for this kind of exchange? It seems like RabbitMQ with AMQP is more suited for this approach.